# Threaded inserts alignment methods

Tags: technique

[image]

How to check the alignment of these inserts as shown in attached pictures?
Also in my company we have a go-no-go gage to test the inserts alignment. How ever we cannot do 100% inspection with the gage as it is time consuming for the team members. Can anyone suggest if I can make a DROP GAGE which can be easy for the Team members to use?

Comment: Please clarify, what alignment do you need to check? Threads being parallel, or at exact distance, or angle relative to flat surface, or .. ?

Comment: Hello Kromster, I want check that if they are parallel to each other. They need to be parallel to each other.

Comment: As you see in picture , the left insert is crooked.

Comment: Do you have constraints on the checking? E.g. do you need to do it visually or you can manufacture a block of steel with two parallel holes drilled at the right alignment or you could employ some kind of optical system?

Comment: Also, what are the tolerances?

Comment: It seems like you could just drill 2 holes in a piece of wood or plastic, and slip it over the 2 screws. If it fits flush against the workpiece, you're fine. If there is a gap on one side or you can't fit it over the 2 screws, the product is defective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about woodworking.  It is two steel threaded elements inserted in a plastic molded element.